# DataGridView reeentrant error when trying to re-bind in CellEndEdit event handler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a custom control, which contains a `DataGridView` (among other controls). This custom control exposes a `DataSource` property, which corresponds to the data source of the constituent `DataGridView`.

It also exposes the `CellEndEdit` event. It is being used to try and set the value of a special column (which cannot be user-edited itself). The strategy is to copy the `DataTable` (source), edit that copy, then re-bind the data:

```
private void MyControl_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable temp = allRecords.Copy();
    string name = MyControl.currentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (temp.Rows[i][0].ToString().Equals(name))
            temp.Rows[i]["Status"] = "Modified";
    }
    
    // re-bind the data
    temp.AcceptChanges();
    MyControl.dataSource = temp; // this is the offending line
}
```

However, this results in the following error:

[image]

As an attempt to solve this, the binding was suspended then resumed, but to no avail:

```
CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[MyControl.dataSource];
cm.SuspendBinding();
MyControl.dataSource = temp;
cm.ResumeBinding();
```

What is the cause of this, and how to fix it?

Comment: Why a _copy_ and not the original `allRecords` ? You can modify the values then call the `AcceptChanges` method. For the `copy` scenario, `Dispose` and `null` the current data source of the DGV before assigning the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with dr null, the “copy” is strange and is definitely the cause of the problem. It is unclear “what” `allRecords` is or if it is a `DataSource` to the grid. If it is… Then it makes no sense to… “copy” the data source, make a single change to it, then re-set it as a data source to the grid, when `allRecords` is already a `DataSource` to the grid. So, you need to clarify what `allRecords` is and if it is a `DataSource` to the grid.

The reason for the error on the line…

```
MyControl.dataSource = temp;
```

Goes something like this… When setting a “NEW” data source to the grid, this will trigger setting a NEW “current cell/row” property in the grid, which in turn will fire the `CellEndEdit`. Hence the re-entrant. You could possibly use a different event, however as commented above, this appears unnecessary if the goal is to “update” a cell in the grid such that the user does not have edit access to that cell.

From the (syntactically incorrect) code it looks like it is getting a `string` from the selected “current row” of the grid at cell zero[0], and assigning it to the string `name`.

```
string name = MyControl.currentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Then a loop through all the rows in the copied table. In each row iteration, the cell at column zero (0) is checked against the `name` variable, then, if they are equal, the cell at column “Status” is set to “modified.” So, this will change the “Status” cell for ALL rows that have `name` as the value in the first cell. Then finally (the problem) re-set the grids data source.

This scenario is a little odd. Considering this code is run EVERYTIME a user edits and leaves a cell. This implies ANY cell changed in the grid may change the “Status” value. If there are cells in the grid that the user can edit AND those cells do not pertain to the “Status”, then the code is going to run unnecessarily. I would think you would want to identify “which” cells are changed first to see if the changed cell actually pertains to the “Status.”

Anyway… The problem you are having is because the code is “changing” the data source in the grid when it shouldn’t. So, to solve this, I will assume that `allRecords` is already a data source to the grid. If this is the case, then simply do not “copy” the table. Make the changes directly in the grids current `DataSource`. In other words, change the line…

```
DataTable temp = allRecords.Copy();
```

TO

```
DataTable temp = (DataTable)MyControl.DataSource;
```

THEN, remove the unnecessary/problematic lines of code…

```
temp.AcceptChanges();
MyControl.dataSource = temp;
```

This change should eliminate the exception.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I will try this tomorrow.